# Materialized view data doesn't update

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-xe

I want to create a materialized view with fast refresh. The view aggregates values from a single table:

```
CREATE TABLE N_INSP_DTSEDIF_PLANTAS (
    IMPORTACION_ID NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL,
    ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    INSPECCION_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE_PLANTA VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
    NUM_VIVIENDAS NUMBER(10),
    SUP_CONSTRUIDA_VIVIENDAS DECIMAL(10,4),
    -- Plus some other columns I don't need    
    CONSTRAINT N_INSP_DTSEDIF_PLANTAS_P PRIMARY KEY (
        IMPORTACION_ID,
        ID
    ) ENABLE,

    CONSTRAINT N_INSP_DTSEDIF_PLANTAS_F FOREIGN KEY (IMPORTACION_ID)
        REFERENCES IMPORTACION (IMPORTACION_ID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ENABLE
);

CREATE INDEX N_INSP_DTSEDIF_PLANTAS_X ON N_INSP_DTSEDIF_PLANTAS (IMPORTACION_ID);

CREATE SEQUENCE N_INSP_DTSEDIF_PLANTAS_S
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 1
MINVALUE 1
CACHE 20;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER N_INSP_DTSEDIF_PLANTAS_T
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON N_INSP_DTSEDIF_PLANTAS
    REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.ID IS NULL THEN
        SELECT N_INSP_DTSEDIF_PLANTAS_S.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM DUAL;
    END IF;
END N_INSP_DTSEDIF_PLANTAS_T;
/
ALTER TRIGGER N_INSP_DTSEDIF_PLANTAS_T ENABLE;
```

I've composed this through trial and error:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON N_INSP_DTSEDIF_PLANTAS
WITH ROWID, SEQUENCE (IMPORTACION_ID, INSPECCION_ID, NUM_VIVIENDAS, SUP_CONSTRUIDA_VIVIENDAS)
INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW V_PLANTAS
REFRESH FAST
AS
SELECT IMPORTACION_ID, INSPECCION_ID,
SUM(NUM_VIVIENDAS) AS NUM_VIVIENDAS, SUM(SUP_CONSTRUIDA_VIVIENDAS) AS SUP_CONSTRUIDA_VIVIENDAS
FROM N_INSP_DTSEDIF_PLANTAS
GROUP BY IMPORTACION_ID, INSPECCION_ID;
```

Objects get created without errors and `SELECT * FROM V_PLANTAS` returns data. However, the view is stalled. New rows added to `N_INSP_DTSEDIF_PLANTAS` don't show up at `V_PLANTAS`.

What did I misunderstand from the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mess of random changes that follow panic and despair I inadvertently dropped the `ON COMMIT` clause:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW V_PLANTAS
REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
AS
-- ...
```

The log itself is also invalid for fast refresh because I also omitted the `PRIMARY KEY` clause. It should be like:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON N_INSP_DTSEDIF_PLANTAS
WITH ROWID, PRIMARY KEY, SEQUENCE (INSPECCION_ID, NUM_VIVIENDAS, SUP_CONSTRUIDA_VIVIENDAS)
INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
```

<sub>(Said that, it's worth noting that materialized tables are not just a simple results cache but a fairly large and complex feature that requires careful planning and maintenance. In many situations is easier to just optimize the underlying query.)</sub>

Comment: I think that you also probably want at least COUNT(NUM_VIVIENDAS) and COUNT(SUP_CONSTRUIDA_VIVIENDAS) in the definition as well, as the fast refresh cannot remove rows from the materialized view if the last occurrence of a particular combination of IMPORTACION_ID and INSPECCION_ID is removed from the base table. Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_mview.htm#CEGGEHHC to see what the capabilities of the MView are.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I didn't even know that was possible. Is it too much abuse if I ask for an example?

Comment: I would actually have a good browse of the data warehousing guide's material on MVs http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/basicmv.htm and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/advmv.htm, which will give you a complete overview of this particular type of MV usage.